# Django Select field - change what is displayed

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a `ModelForm` which is rendering a `select` field because it points to a `ForeignKey`. When the form is rendered, it's displaying the options based the `ForeignKey`'s `__unicode__` definition.

For example, I have a `select` field in a form to pick a contact from a `Contact` model. The `Contact` model has:

```
def __unicode__(self):
  return self.first_name
```

Thus, my list of contacts in my `select` field only show first names.

I know I could just change the `__unicode__` definition, but I want to know how to change what is presented int the `select` options based on where that `select` field is presented. In other words, in some forms, I need to show something like:

`{{ contact.first_name}} -- {{ contact.phone_number }}`

and in other areas I want to show just:

`{{ contact.first_name }}`

How do I go about adjusting the `ModelForm` so that *that* specific field, the `select` field which is pointing to the `ForeignKey` model `Contact` displays the full name of the contact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand this is a `ModelChoiceField` so you can override the `label_from_instance`. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) for reference.

```
class YourNewChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "%s -- %s" % (obj.name, obj.phone_number)
```

Inside the form use your new field.

```
class YourForm(ModelForm)
    # As you'd normally define your ModelChoiceField field
    contact = YourNewChoiceField(queryset=...) 

    class Meta:
        fields = ['contact', ...]
```

Comment: This is promising -- but how would this apply to `ModelForm` where for the form is built based on the `models.Model` I create. So instead of `class MyForm(forms.Form)` I am using `class MyForm(ModelForm)`. From there, I define the `model` to use, and which fields from that model to use. I'm not quite sure how I'd assign the new `YourNewChoiceField` to the ModelForm (if that makes sense)

Comment: I may have found my answer [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) but it looks to only be available in 1.9 whereas I'm using 1.8

Comment: `label_from_instance` is also available in [Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield). As for your first question you simple redefine the field in your form, I updated the answer.